# Compatibility mode in IE 11

Tags: compatibility, meta-tags, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE11. My application is based in IE9. 
We have set the following meta-tags in the head of our pages.`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

But when I open in my browser, it always opens in Edge document mode.
I always end up enforcing the document mode in developer's toolbar.

Could you please help figure out if I am missing anything in my browser?
I tried uninstalling and re-installing IE as well.

p.s. The same is not happening in other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else faces the same issue, try not to use localhost in the url. Use your IP address instead.